# Using Disjoint Sets in a Switch Case

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to figure out why `getLabelForType` works but `getOtherLableForType` fails typing:

```
export const things = {
    THING1: 'THING1',
    THING2: 'THING2',
}
export type Thing = $Keys<typeof things>

type Empty = 'empty type' & 'nothing there'

export default function unexpectedCase(impossible: Empty): void {
    throw new Error(`Unexpected case ${impossible}`)
}

export function getLabelForType(thing: Thing): string {
    switch (thing) {
        case 'THING1':
            return 'Thing 1'
        case 'THING2':
            return 'Thing 2'
        default:
            unexpectedCase(thing)
            return ''
    }
}


export function getOtherLabelForType(thing: Thing): string {
    (things.THING1: Thing)
    switch (thing) {
        case things.THING1:
            return 'Thing 1'
        case things.THING1:
            return 'Thing 2'
        default:
            unexpectedCase(thing)
            return ''
    }
}
```

See the [tryflow working example](https://tryflow.org/?code=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)

Comment: No particular reason I don't think, it's just that Flow does not do a sophisticated enough analysis to understand this case. Maybe someday.

Also worth noting that there is an actual empty type: just `empty`. You don't need to define your own.

Comment: Good tip on the `empty` type, thanks!